# Why is the Polyline not showing?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

Here is my whole code to show a simple line:

```
public class MapUIViewController : UIViewController
{
    MKMapView map;

    public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
        CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = new CLLocationCoordinate2D(38.8895, -77.036168);
        map = new MKMapView()
        {
            MapType = MKMapType.Hybrid,
            Region = new MKCoordinateRegion(loc, new MKCoordinateSpan(0.1, 0.1)),
            Frame = View.Bounds,
        };
        View = map;
        ShowLine(loc, new CLLocationCoordinate2D(loc.Latitude + 1, loc.Longitude + 1));
    }
        
    void ShowLine(CLLocationCoordinate2D start, CLLocationCoordinate2D end)
    {
        MKGeodesicPolyline polyline = MKGeodesicPolyline.FromCoordinates(new CLLocationCoordinate2D[] { start, end });
        map.AddOverlay(polyline);
        map.OverlayRenderer = rend;
    }

    MKOverlayRenderer rend(MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlay)
    {
        if (overlay is MKGeodesicPolyline line)
            return new MKPolylineRenderer(line) { LineWidth = 3, StrokeColor = UIColor.Red, FillColor = UIColor.Brown, Alpha = 1 };
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

It shows the location specified, but does not show the line.

(<sub>The code is in C# (using Xamarin.ios) but it should be similar in Swift and Objective C, and my question is about the renderer which is an ios feature, not about a language feature</sub>).

I must be missing something, but I can't find it.

Comment: you should assign the renderer FIRST

Comment: @Jason Wow, that was simple. Thanks. (You can change your comment into an answer so I can accept it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to assign the renderer BEFORE you add the line.  Doing it the other way means that no renderer exists when the line is added so it will not be drawn

wrong

```
map.AddOverlay(polyline);
map.OverlayRenderer = rend;
```

right

```
map.OverlayRenderer = rend;
map.AddOverlay(polyline);
```

Comment: Thanks again. (Can't accept for another 7 minutes)